# cakephp preform query like: where md5(column) = $hash

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, md5

He i'm moving a project to a cakephp project.
In this project I put a md5(id) in my url like 
http://example.com?hash=424bbf597a23a198b69b1b8cc4674260

I get the hash from the url and search in my database which client is requested like:
$hash = $_GET['hash'];

SELECT * FROM sites
WHERE md5(id) = $hash

is something like this possible in cakephp?

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL, which includes `MD5` function, yes you can like so:

```
$sites = $this->Site->find('all',
    array('conditions' => array('MD5(Site.id)' => $_GET['hash'])));
```

Comment: Why $_GET and not the request object?

Comment: Because the asker uses `$_GET['hash']` in his question. One man's opinion: There's no need to confuse the question asker with "additional" code not pertinent to the question itself. Note to all: You can use `$this->request->query('hash')`, which is the CakePHP way, in place of `$_GET['hash']`.

Comment: thanks! that worked for me and yes Jacob I also use $this->request->query :-)

Answer (score -1):

in Model:

```
$this->query("SELECT * FROM sites WHERE md5(id) = '$hash'");
```

should work.

Comment: if you think this answer is not helpful/wrong please comment on it so I can fix.